# I would like to grey out the submit button until required fields in a pdf form have been filled out

Tags: pdf, submit

I am recently task with collecting data using a pdf form, some fields in the form are required but not all fields, I have created a submit button and the department will received the form fill out, now the form needs to be reset when submitted. so i add a button to submit the form and then reset it. the problem is that if someone fills the form and hits submit missing a required field then when they hit ok all the fields are being reset and the person needs to start over. Please Advice.
My idea is to gray out the submit button until all the required fields are fill out, no idea how to do this on adobe pro.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you immediately reset the form after submitting (what happens when the submit fails?), greying out or making read-only is a way to go.

Assuming that you did set the required property for the required fields, you could add the following snipped to your Calculation script:

```
var cnt = 0 ;
for (var i = 0 ; i < this.numFields ; i++) {
   var mf = this.getNthFieldName(i) ;
   if (mf.type != "button" && mf.type != "signature") {
      if (mf.required == true && mf.value == mf.defaultValue) {
         cnt++ ;
      }
   }
}
if (cnt > 0) {
   this.getField("mySubmitButton").readonly = true ;
} else {
   this.getField("mySubmitButton").readonly = false ;
}
```

And that should do it.

However, this approach is not very efficient, and for bigger number of fields and just a few required ones, it might be better to create an array of the required field names, and loop through this array instead of all fields.